# Page not loading after interaction, stuck on blank page even after implicit wait

Tags: java, macos, webdriver

the code below inputs username/password and clicks on login button but the next page won't load, stuck on the URL even after 20-sec wait. I am using Mac, anyone else experience this problem?

I have tried thread.sleep and explicit wait

here is part of the code:
public class Tests {

```
static WebDriver driver;
String baseURL = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php";
static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
ECommerceNotLoggedInClass initialPage;
ECommerceLoginPageClass loginPage;
MyAccountPage testMyAccount;

@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(baseURL);
}

@Test(priority = 0)
public void verifyPageTitleAndClickForLogin() {
    initialPage = new ECommerceNotLoggedInClass(driver);
    Assert.assertEquals(initialPage.getTitle(), "My Store");
    initialPage.clickSignIn();
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void signInAndCheckRightPage() {
    loginPage = new ECommerceLoginPageClass(driver);
    waitUnitElementPresent(loginPage.loginInputForm);
    Assert.assertEquals(loginPage.getLogInPageTitle(), "Login - My Store");
        loginPage.login();
```

Error message seen in console:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.cssSelector: #login_form' (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at Tests.waitUnitElementPresent(Tests.java:62)
    at Tests.signInAndCheckRightPage(Tests.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#login_form"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Zornitsas-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '2601:246:5600:305a:0:0:0:974c%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe7..., userDataDir: /var/folders/wf/dbzc1bjx021...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50995}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 79b9669510b099033ef4c3ec52baa8df
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=#login_form}
```

Comment: The error message displays that the page has not the element **"method":"css selector","selector":"#login_form** ,  this is the reason you couldn't see the page loaded.

Comment: Right. the problem is that the page gets stuck and not loading..not sure how to force it to load.. it would work 1 out of 3 times but mostly it hangs

Comment: some times giving thread.sleep before click helps. try once

Comment: Thanks murali but that didnt work. I click on signIn link -> Thread.sleep(5000); but the resulting page wont load.. I know it opens the url and clicks on the link and then its just wont load.. I can trick it by grabbing the url and using driver.get again but its not the ideal solution